# nth-child not alternating div colour

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the `.links-image` div that should have a coloured border and alternating with a white border however the colour for all borders remains the same. changing the colour on  `.links-image:nth-child(odd)` will change the colour for all borders not just odd

http://jsfiddle.net/rcojb60u/

```
<div class="fullcontainer">
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="links-container">


        <div class="links-wrap">
            <div class="grid grid--flexcells grid--gutters grid--full gridsm--full gridmd--1of2 gridlg--1of2">
                <div class="grid-cell">
                    <div class="box">
                        <a href="http://{!! $linksitem->link !!}">
                        <div class="links-image">
                            <img class="u-full-width-links" src="images/links/{{ $linksitem->img }}" />
                                <div class="links-text-bg">
                                    <div class="links-text-left">
                                        <div class="links-text-top"><span class="links-text-url">test text</span></div>
                                        <div class="links-text-bottom"><span class="rev-img-tag">text</span></div>  
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>              
                </div>
                <div class="grid grid--flexcells grid--gutters grid--full gridsm--full gridmd--1of2 gridlg--1of2">
                <div class="grid-cell">
                    <div class="box">
                        <a href="http://{!! $linksitem->link !!}">
                        <div class="links-image">
                            <img class="u-full-width-links" src="images/links/{{ $linksitem->img }}" />
                                <div class="links-text-bg">
                                    <div class="links-text-left">
                                        <div class="links-text-top"><span class="links-text-url">test text</span></div>
                                        <div class="links-text-bottom"><span class="rev-img-tag">text</span></div>  
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>              
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
        </div><!--links container-->
    </div><!--content end-->



</div><!--container end-->
</div><!--fullcontainer end-->

.links-container{width:100%; height:auto; }
.links-image { position: relative; width: 100%; border: 10px solid #fff;}
.links-image:nth-child(odd) { position: relative; height:200px;width: 200px; border: 10px solid #282828;}
.links-text-bg{ display:flex; flex-direction:row; position: absolute; left: 0; bottom:0;width: 100%; height:60px; 
background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */ background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75); padding-left:20px; }
.links-text-left{flex: 0 0 100%; height:70px;}
.links-text-top{width:100%; height:30px; line-height:2; }
.links-text-bottom{width:100%; height:40px; padding-top:2px;}


.links-text-url{color: #DB016C; font-size: 20px; padding-top: 5px; }
.links-wrap{margin-left:0px;}
```

Comment: `:nth-child` refers to sibling elements, and your `links-image` elements are not siblings. Also, please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question, don't just link to jsFiddle. You saw the warning yet tried to sidestep it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your .grid contains another .grid, so even if you put the :nth-child on the right selector it won't work. try fixing your code, then apply the :nth-child to the .grid-cell

```
.grid-cell:nth-child(odd) .links-image {
  //put here whatever style you want
}
```